# Resharper "Save" does not save to custom layer

Tags: cloud, settings, resharper, layer

I want to save my Resharper settings in the cloud so I can use the same settings on 2 computers. So I created a new Settings Layer in Resharper (with the cloud file). But when I press "Save" in Resharper Options the settings are not saved to the file. Instead the settings are saved to "This Computer" Layer (but not to the custom layers below it!). I have to use "Save To" and save explicitely to the layer. If I forget "Save To" it can have unintended consequences when using the file with the cloud - so I would like to change that.

Is there a way to make "Save" also save to the file of the custom layer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the logic for how ReSharper saves its settings - they get written out based on priority, and it looks like the default layer takes precedence over a custom layer attached to the default layer (you can [raise a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) if you think this should be changed).

You can [read more about layers](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/help/Reference__Settings_Layers.html), and how they work in the help (check out the See Also section for links to blog posts with more info).

Alternatively, you can use the [JetBox](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.JetBox/) plugin, which will synchronise the default layer via DropBox.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to select a *default* save location. However, you can start changing options by bringing up that dialog, and double click the file. Then, when you press save, it is definitely saved to the file and you cannot accidentally save to the wrong location.